# Installing an ISO onto a local hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, iso-image

I just got an old 1997 Dell Dimension XPS Pro200n and I'm trying to figure out how to install an OS on it. Unfortunately, it does not have any USB's to boot from USB, and my previous experiences with booting over LAN were ineffective. So, I would like to try and install an ISO onto a local hard drive that I've plugged into my main computer, and then switch that hard drive over to the old machine and boot from it.

Is it possible to take an ISO (in this case, windows 2000, though, ideally, I'd like to do something like linux mint, or lubuntu) and install it locally on a hard drive, without booting from a live usb?

I'm currently running ubuntu 20.04 on my host machine.

Comment: yes, I'll edit and make that more clear

Answer (score 0):

So you want to connect the HDD to another computer, load the OS or its installer onto it and then move the disk to target computer?

For **Linux**, just install it and move the HDD. It will work fine. Make sure to use the legacy mode (aka CSM, aka BIOS mode).

For **Windows**, use [WinNTSetup](https://msfn.org/board/topic/149612-winntsetup-v450/). It's Windows software, so you'll need a host running Windows to use it. You may be able to run it on Wine. A VM with physical disk passthrough and evaluation copy of Windows 10 will do just fine too.